# Select records that fit criteria in another record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a procedure that I want to return only when a second procedure was selected.

```
Id  Name      Procedure 
1  Jim Smith  Procedure1
2  Jim Smith  Procedure2
```

I would like the first record returned only if Jim Smith had both procedures.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* 
  from table t1 
  join table t2 
    on t2.name = t1.name 
   and t1.procedure = 'Procedure1' 
   and t2.procedure = 'Procedure2'
```